# Are files saved in File.cacheDirectory() automatically deleted at the end of a session?

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, caching, air

Building a desktop AIR application on Windows 7 using [`cacheDirectory`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#cacheDirectory), is the application responsible for emptying it, or is this handled by the OS?

My understanding is that when targeting iOS, the OS handles clearing this cache directory, but I'm not sure on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [a blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/02/13/preventing-automatic-cloud-backup-on-ios-devices/) on Adobe's site:

> On Mac OSX and Android, `File.cacheDirectory` points to the `Caches` directory (`<APPLICATION_HOME>/Library/Caches` on Mac and `<APPLICATION_HOME>/caches` directory on Android).
>
> **While on Windows, it points to the parent directory being used by `File.createTempDirectory`.**

Based on that, from the [Working with the file system](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/Filesystem_05.html#1028551) page within the Adobe Help Resource Center:

> You may want to delete the temporary directory before closing the application, as it is **not automatically deleted**.